# SAS Batch Jobs Intermittently Failing

Tags: sas, batch-processing, event-viewer, isaserver

We have a high volume of SAS batch jobs that are run using a scheduling/polling tool called VisualCron. Say 100+ VisualCron instances (one each for each of our customers) calls a VBScript file that polls an SQL "jobs" table and identifies the work queue.

For each VisualCron instance, we have BAT files that call the SAS programs via SAS.EXE, such as:

sas.exe -sysin "sasprogram.sas" -log "somelogfile.log" -config "I:\Program Files\SAS\SASFoundation\9.2\nls\1d\SASV9.CFG"

I believe, under high load, we intermittently see jobs failing. The Windows Event Viewer Application log shows the following errors - but I'm unable to search on Google for what these really mean and why/when they occur. Any one have any experience around what these could be?

[image: Windows Event Viewer - Multiple errors]

[image: Error Example 1]

[image: Error Example 2]

Comment: By the look of the error message in the last picture, it seems like SAS is trying to access a locked file (hence the `.lck` postfix on the file). Datasets have "pages," so I think it's just saying it can't read the dataset, which makes sense if it's locked.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think the .lck rename is automatic (and not necessarily indicative of a conflict).  However, the general concept (competing over reading the same file) is likely the culprit.  Your SAS log for the job may have more useful feedback (or not, but it's worth looking).

Comment: I would say that having 100s of simultaneously running SAS sessions all hitting roughly the same files is not going to be a good idea; you should be using SAS/SHARE and a server to manage this.

Comment: Thanks Joe. Unfortunately, in these cases the log file specified against the -log parameter isn't even getting generated (is there another SAS log location to look at?). I know we have a SAS 9.2 server, but not sure how to see if we are using a "SAS/SHARE" or not, is there an obvious way to tell one way or the other?

Comment: Take a look under %APPDATA%\SAS\LOGS for the user running the jobs (SVC_VC_CLUSTER), it could give you some hints.